# About the non-constant harmonic function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I want to see the steps for the proof of this result:

If $u:\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is a non-constant harmonic function, then $u^{-1}(c)$ is unbounded in $\mathbb R^n$ for any $c \in \mathbb R$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step I.** A non-constant harmonic function $u$ takes each real value. If it does not take the value $c\in\mathbb R$, then its range, due to intermiediate value theorem, would be a subset of $(c,\infty)$ or of $(-\infty,c)$. But according to [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_functions#Liouville.27s_theorem), in such case $u$ would be constant.

**Step II.** If $u(x_0)=c$, then Mean Value Theorem for harmonic functions says that
$$
c=u(x_0)=\frac{1}{|S_r|}\int_{S_r} u(x+y)\,dy,
$$ 
i.e., $u(x_0)$ is the mean value of $u$ on the sphere $|x-x_0|=r$, which implies that $u$ takes $c$ on every sphere $|x-x_0|=r$.

Comment: @ Yiorgos S. Smyrlis: This fact does not apply to analytic function.

Comment: It only applies to its real and imaginary parts.

Comment: @ Yiorgos S. Smyrlis: Can we find conditions on analytic functions, so that happened.